# Не применяется иконка приложения WPF

Tags: wpf, иконки

Меняю иконку приложения через свойства проекта но .exe файл не[image: фото] меняется

Comment: Ну, на скрине видно, что иконка задана. Значит проблем нет. Если она у вас "старая", то у Windows есть некий кэш иконок, из-за чего он иногда может давать временно старый результат. Попробуйте удалить файл и пересобрать, либо просто перенесите в другую директорию, ну или просто подождите. На крайний случай сбросьте кэш иконок.

Comment: я пересобрал раз 10 наверное, подожду, сразу спрошу как можно очистить кэш иконок?

Comment: всё, надо было перенести в другую папку

Comment: @Katrg простое переименование файла тоже бы помогло